# Is it possible to build/export android apps within android app?

Tags: android

I'm still not too experienced with more complex apps, so here is my question - would it be possible to create an app builder for android? I mean, something like game creator app that could export game apks for future publishing. If so, how to get started to set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi, A.Stephen..**
That's a great question, and the simple answer is **yes**

I once looked into this a few years ago and I found the app called AIDE ( Android Integrated Development Environment )

This app is a monthly subscription based software, however I have been a long time user, and I know a few tricks around the heavy subscription costs.

OK to begin with, I figured that I can type faster on my Android than I can on my computer, so why not start developing directly from my device... I could have my test device, my every day device and my development console all in one ... Since then, I've never looked back.

Juggling USB cords and navigating ridiculous hidden settings to test your software and just the headache of so many options on Android Studio lead me to discover AIDE, it is a simple solution and good example for this answer.

To get past the ridiculous monthly FEE, you have Two options... Intel provided a free license for Android development to anyone that downloaded the software.. You just need to select Expert at the start up and Accept the free license ...

The other method is a bit of a trick,

Back before the day's of Subscription based software, you needed to buy what's called a ( Premium Key ).. This is a separate application that you would pay for .. The first application checks that you've paid by seeing if you had the Premium Key installed ...

AIDE still offers the Premium Key for sale on the Play Store...

The trick is, you only need to buy and install the cheaper Premium Key app, And that saves literally hundreds of dollars compared to a monthly subscription.

In total I spent about $14 and now I never have to pay again, the monthly subscription is a similar price ! every month.

The premium key gives you everything you need to develope Android software, including Publishing ( Custom Signatures ) and Pushing to GitHub ... .

If you would like to develop your own software, I suggest having a look at the libraries used within AIDE.

If you like AIDE, like I do.. I suggest grabbing the UI Designer companion app.

[UI Designer ( around $5 )](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.designer)

[Premium Key App ( $17 AUD )](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.premium.key)

[App Itself ( Free Download )](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui)